# uno-platform wasm debugging

Tags: uno-platform

Still running into wasm debugging.  I am on debug and a new project do work but not the project that I stared 8 months ago.  I have deleted bin file and obj and user temp files.

```
<PackageReference Include="Uno.UI.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.0-dev.83" />
<PackageReference Include="Uno.UI.RemoteControl" Version="3.2.0-dev.83" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" />
<PackageReference Include="Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap" Version="1.5.0-dev.57" />
<PackageReference Include="Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer" Version="1.5.0-dev.57" PrivateAssets="all" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused by old packages. Following [instructions on this page](https://platform.uno/blog/debugging-uno-platform-webassembly-apps-in-visual-studio-2019/) and [there](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap#upgrading-from-previous-versions-of-the-unowasmbootstrap-package) should solve your problem:

1. Update `Uno.UI` to latest version
2. Update `Uno.WasmBootstrap` & `Uno.UI.RemoteControl` to latest versions
3. Add reference to `Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer`
4. Open your `.csproj` and remove any `<DotNetCliToolReference />`

It should work after that.

Comment: I am on the newest build for all packages and do not have DotNetCliToolReference